# PHP multiple file upload uploads same image 5 times instead of all files

Tags: php, file-upload

Hey guys I am really struggling with my code. When I try to upload multiple images it uploads the same image 5 times instead of uploading both images. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Here is the var_dumb($_FILES)

```
array(1) {
  ["userfile"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "test1.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpdDGCy2"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(1768037)
  }
}
```

Here is my upload function:

```
if(count($_FILES['userfile'])){
    foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $file){
$alt=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['alt']);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
if (($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] == 0) && ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0))
{
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
} 
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfiles"]["name"]));
if((($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    ||($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/jpeg")
    ||($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/png")
    ||($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/pjpeg")
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)))
    {
        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content =fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $SourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($content);
        $SourceWidth = imagesx($SourceImage);
        $SourceHeight=imagesy($SourceImage);
        $DestWidth=100;
        $DestHeight=130;
        if ($SourceHeight> $SourceWidth)
        {$ratio = $DestHeight / $SourceHeight;
        $newHeight = $DestHeight;
        $newWidth = $sourceWidth * $ratio;
        }
        else
        {
            $ratio = $DestWidth / $SourceWidth;
            $newWidth = $DestWidth;
            $newHeight = $SourceHeight * $ratio;
        }
        $DestinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($DestinationImage, $SourceImage, 0,0,0,0,$DestWidth, $DestHeight, $SourceHeight, $SourceWidth);
        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($DestinationImage);
        $BinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $thumb = addslashes($BinaryThumbnail);
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);
        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

         mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO files (username, name, size, content, type, link, alt, thumbnail) VALUES ('$username', '$fileName', '$fileSize', '$content', '$fileType', 1, '$alt', '$thumb')") or die('Error, query failed'); 
           echo "<script>alert('The file has been uploaded');location.replace('uploaded.php');</script>";
           unlink ($_FILES['username']['tmp_name']);

    }else{ 
           echo "<script>alert('Please upload an image');location.replace('upload.php');</script>";
    }
}
}
}
```

Here is upload form:

```
    <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <h1>Upload a file</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php">
<div id="filediv">
<div id="imagefiles">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<label>Upload File:
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" id="userfile" multiple></label>
<label>Alt Text: <input name="alt" type="text"></label>
 </div>
 </div>
<br>

<input type="button" value="Add Another File" onclick="copyDiv()"/>
<input name="UploadFile" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You're referencing `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` _inside_ your foreach loop; you need to replace all those references with `$file`, as that contains the variable you're currently working with.

Comment: So I do $fileName = $_FILES $file;
$tmpName  = $_FILES $file;
$fileSize = $_FILES $file;
$fileType = $_FILES $file;
? Sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: Your foreach loop steps through the array of files; so instead of `$_FILES['userfile']['name'];`, you need `$file['name'];`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$_FILES['userfile']` inside of loop use your variable from foreach, `$file`.

Also use `var_dump` on `$_FILES` to check how it was sent.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload multiple files at a time, it is very much possible that server will accept only one file. I have this problem once, and I fixed it by ajax file uploading. Ajax file uploading is also very useful because users don't have to wait so that all files are transferred to server. You can use this. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 0):

you can try `for loop` instead of `foreach`....as:

```
if(count($_FILES['userfile'])){
   for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['userfile']);$i++) {
$alt=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['alt']);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
if (($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] == 0) && ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0))
{
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
} 
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfiles"]["name"]));
if((($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    ||($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/jpeg")
    ||($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/png")
    ||($_FILES["userfile"]["type"]=="image/pjpeg")
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)))
    {
        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content =fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $SourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($content);
        $SourceWidth = imagesx($SourceImage);
        $SourceHeight=imagesy($SourceImage);
        $DestWidth=100;
        $DestHeight=130;
        if ($SourceHeight> $SourceWidth)
        {$ratio = $DestHeight / $SourceHeight;
        $newHeight = $DestHeight;
        $newWidth = $sourceWidth * $ratio;
        }
        else
        {
            $ratio = $DestWidth / $SourceWidth;
            $newWidth = $DestWidth;
            $newHeight = $SourceHeight * $ratio;
        }
        $DestinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($DestinationImage, $SourceImage, 0,0,0,0,$DestWidth, $DestHeight, $SourceHeight, $SourceWidth);
        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($DestinationImage);
        $BinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $thumb = addslashes($BinaryThumbnail);
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);
        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

         mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO files (username, name, size, content, type, link, alt, thumbnail) VALUES ('$username', '$fileName', '$fileSize', '$content', '$fileType', 1, '$alt', '$thumb')") or die('Error, query failed'); 
           echo "<script>alert('The file has been uploaded');location.replace('uploaded.php');</script>";
           unlink ($_FILES['username']['tmp_name'][$i]);

    }else{ 
           echo "<script>alert('Please upload an image');location.replace('upload.php');</script>";
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: I tried the for loop. It really only pulls it one from one file....and for some reason its breaking my table and breaks the file name into each spot of the array instead of the entire file.
When I echo the file count I get 5 even though i only uploaded 1 file.
5
array(1) {
  ["userfile"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "1.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/php7LU76b"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(780831)
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I would consider using a JS/AJAX solution here as opposed to php. Uploading multiple files is a little cumbersome with php due to load times and long page refreshes while your code executes, with no real feedback to the user as to what is going on behind the scenes.

I have used [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) a few times and it works well.